# ayuda tabla automática en HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<form id='form_feed_buscar' name="form_feed_buscar" action='buscador_comuna.php' method="POST">
<div id="contenedor_principal" class="contenedorPronosticoRegion" style="background-color: REBECCAPURPLE">
<a href="#" onclick="ver_detalleregion('01a');" id="1">
    <img id="r01a" alt="I Región" title="Región de Arica-Parinacota" style="opacity: 0.5;z-index: 5;position: absolute;left: 82px;top: 41px;width: 25px;" src="/img/regiones/reg1a.png" onmouseover="javascript:marca(this);" onmouseout="javascript:desmarca(this);" > 
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ver_detalleregion('r01b');" id="2">
    <img id="r01b" title="Región de Tarapá" style="opacity: 0.5;z-index: 5;position: absolute;left: 84px;top: 67px;width: 32px;" src="/img/regiones/reg1b.png" onmouseover="javascript:marca(this);" onmouseout="javascript:desmarca(this);">
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="ver_detalleregion('r02');" id="3">
    <img id="r02" title="Región de Antofagasta" style="opacity: 0.5;z-index: 5;position: absolute;left: 77px;top: 102px;width: 61px;" src="/img/regiones/reg2.png" onmouseover="javascript:marca(this);" onmouseout="javascript:desmarca(this);">
</a>
<a href="#"onclick="ver_detalleregion('r03');" id="4">
    <img id="r03" title="Región de Atacama" style="opacity: 0.5;z-index: 5;position: absolute;left: 65px;top: 182px;width: 53px;" src="/img/regiones/reg3.png" onmouseover="javascript:marca(this);" onmouseout="javascript:desmarca(this);">
</a>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 50px;  width: 200px;" id="tabla1" hidden="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
            <th width="30%">Region </th>              
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

tengo la funcion

```
function ver_detalleregion(val) {
            $('#tabla1').show();                        

        }
```

La idea es que la funcion ver_detalleregion me cargue una tabla en mysql los datos que tengan la región seleccionada, cada  región esta compuesta por un HREF y IMG

Comment: Nosotros no generamos código, si no deseas poner el código php lo entendemos, pero debes de poner mas información acerca de tu código javascript, le faltan muchos detalles importantes al código, por ejemplo, que haz intentado?, no veo que hayas puesto como creas la tabla dinámica (si es tu objetivo), no veo donde recibes los datos traidos por PHP, que haz intentado?, no basta con decirlo, porfavor edita la pregunta y añade el código necesario, por supuesto tambien serviria de mucho añadir un ejemplo del json resultado o valor o valores que deseas traer (en formato JSON).

Comment: Ademas recuerda... no somos adivinos, no sabemos la estructura de tu tabla ni sus tipos de datos ni nada que tu sabes, estas proponiendonos adivinar a crear una tabla con datos que no conocemos apartir de una sentencia hacia mysql que no conocemos.